# How to include claims in JWT token?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, azure-active-directory, authorization, claims-based-identity

Hi I am developing web application in .Net core. I have implemented V2 Authentication. Now I have requirement to add Authorization. The requirement states that First,

> It should not be the job of the application to gather the claims of
>   the user, they should be available in the users JWT. Second, 
>   Permissions with an application will be granted based on claims.

Below is my authentication code.

```
 services
               .AddAuthentication(o =>
               {
                   o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

               })
               .AddJwtBearer(o =>
               {
                   o.Authority = azureActiveDirectoryOptions.Authority;

                   o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                   {

                       ValidAudiences = new List<string>
                       {
                          azureActiveDirectoryOptions.AppIdUri,
                          azureActiveDirectoryOptions.ClientId
                       },
                   };
               });

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {

                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Can someone help me to add claims based Authorization? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: Thanks but my question was how to include claims in JWT token? Any idea on this?

Comment: Middleware will help map claims in token to your application user claims , do you want to add custom claims in AAD issued tokens ?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I want to add custom claims in AAD issued token. May I know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use code as below to add custom claim in JWT token.

```
public string createToken()
{
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    //create a identity and add claims to the user which we want to log in
    ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
    {
        new Claim("UserName", "joey"),
        new Claim("Email","xxx@test.com")
    });

    const string sec = "yoursecurityKey";
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sec));
    var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

    //create the jwt
    var jwtSecurityToken = handler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(
        "issuer",
        "Audience",
        new ClaimsIdentity(claimsIdentity),
        DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
        DateTime.Now,
        signingCredentials);
    var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

    return tokenString;
}
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://blog.zaven.co/user-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-rsa-jwt-tokens-part-3/).

Update:

If so, you could use [JwtBearerEvents](https://joonasw.net/view/adding-custom-claims-aspnet-core-2) to add claim.

```
 .AddJwtBearer(o =>
 {
     //Additional config snipped
     o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
     {
         OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
         {
             //Get the calling app client id that came from the token produced by Azure AD
             string clientId = ctx.Principal.FindFirstValue("appid");
             var claims = new List<Claim>
             {
                 new Claim("UserName", "joey")
             };
             var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

             ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
         }
     };
});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. Really I am not able to understand this code because already my above code generates the token and it does authentication also properly. What I want to do  is I want to add some claims in my token and based on that claim I want to validate or authorize. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Now my claims contains new custom claim UserName Joey. Just trying to understand when did claim added to the token. In which step claim is added.

Answer (score 1):

For authorization part , you can [add app roles in your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps) , assign roles to users/groups , so that `roles` will include in token after user login and consent , your application could use policy to restrict access based on `roles` claim .

Another approach is to [use Azure AD Groups and Group Claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims#configure-the-azure-ad-application-registration-for-group-attributes) . The difference is your application should check `groups` claim ,

Comment: Thanks so what is the difference between groupMembershipClaims and optionalClaims? So far what I have understood is, based on the azure ad role, role based authorization will work. But how Group claims will work?

Comment: assign user to different groups , so in tokens there is `groups` claim shows which groups current user is member of , you can then create policy and check the claim .groupMembershipClaims is one of optional Claims of aad .

Comment: So claim based authorization is same as group based authorization? Also what is the difference between claims and policy based authorization?

Comment: That seems you don't understand the process . Claims in AAD issued tokens are controlled by Azure AD ,  you application will get the map the claims from token to application user claims .  If you want to modify the tokens in AAD , the accept answer won't work  , The code is used to add claim to user claim in your application . That is nothing to do with your AAD token claims .

Comment: @Niranjan . Using roles or groups just leads to check different claim(one is roles , one is groups) in your application . In .net core , you can use policy to check the user claims and use [Authorize] attribute to trigger the authorization .